# Is a dryer vent tube being compressed like this up to code?

Tags: code-compliance, dryer, exhaust-vent

There's a 4" dryer pipe in my wall that is smashed slightly in order to get it to fit into the wall made with 2v4s. Is this OK?

[image: Wall Photo]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't answer whether it complies with code or not since that depends on where you are, but I doubt it would matter.

It's compressed some, but the volume is the same; it's just a different shape, and only slightly at that. Codes regarding airflow (and water flow) issues are mostly concerned with turns. A 90 degree angle will limit airflow whereas a larger radius bend would not, but the straight runs are rarely if ever a problem.

Comment: My concern with smashing the pipe (and why I think it could matter) is a seam may have split open and hot, moist air would get ejected into the void, but from the picture, that doesn't appear to have happened. So, I think it *could* matter.

Comment: +1 But the volume isn't *quite* the same, it's slightly less. A circle is the shape having the most area for a given length of perimeter, so an oval made from the same piece of pipe has slightly less area and therefore less volume (imagining continuing to flatten the oval until the sides touched when there would be zero volume).  But the difference seems negligible in this context. The concern about a theoretical split seam from @Ghost would be the greater issue. I agree with your overall conclusion.